# Unwanted gaps appear on the template (Django)

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I give the products to the page with the loop in the template, but there is a problem. There is a gap on the page and I can't find the reason. Most likely because of HTML codes. I will be glad if you help.

This gap in the middle
[image]

products.html

```
<!-- STORE -->
                <div id="store">
                    <!-- row -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <!-- Product Single -->
                        {% for product in products %}
                        {% if product.available %}
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                            <div class="product product-single">
                                <div class="product-thumb">
                                    <div class="product-label">
                                        <span>New</span>
                                        {% if product.sale %}
                                        <span class="sale">-{{product.sale}}%</span>
                                        {% endif %}
                                    </div>
                                    <button class="main-btn quick-view"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i> Göz At</button>
                                    <img src="{{product.main_image.url}}" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="product-body">
                                    {% if product.sale %}
                                    <h3 class="product-price">{{product.discount}} AZN <del class="product-old-price">{{product.price}} AZN</del></h3>
                                    {% else %}
                                    <h3 class="product-price">{{product.price}} AZN</h3>
                                    {% endif %}
                                    <div class="product-rating">
                                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-star-o empty"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <h2 class="product-name"><a href="#">{{product.name}}</a></h2>
                                    <div class="product-btns">
                                        <button class="main-btn icon-btn"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></button>
                                        <button class="main-btn icon-btn"><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i></button>
                                        <button class="primary-btn add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Səbətə At</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                        <!-- /Product Single -->

                    </div>
                    <!-- /row -->
                </div>
<!-- /STORE -->
```

Comment: have you tried removing `{% if product.available %}`, see if the error is still there

Comment: Yes, I tried. The same thing, again

Comment: Does it appear only for the current page or is it reproducible on other pages ?

Comment: Yes for the current page. After adding or deleting a new product, the same problem still occurs

Comment: Just to be sure that it's not from the stylesheet, try to retrieve only 6 products from the current page and see what happens.

Comment: ok i will try. Thanks